# Ambari resource dir?

Tags: java, hadoop

Hi all, for my Hadoop environment, I'm trying to setup CentOS clients to act as datanodes with the Ambari management system.

However, I'm running into the problem during the startup of the datanodes, here is the error log:

```
Fail: Execution of 'mkdir -p /tmp/HDP-artifacts/ ; curl -kf --retry 10     http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8080/resources//jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz -o /tmp/HDP-artifacts//jdk-     7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz' returned 22.   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time         Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

So I believe that there's a problem where the client can't obtain the .tar.gz file from the Ambari server. Is there a workaround for this? I was think maybe I could just download the file from the web and stick it into the sandbox, but I don't know where the resource directory is for the sandbox.

```
What I've tried so far: 
1.) rebooting the entire environment
2.) making changes within the python code to curl out to the web
3.) manualy installing the same jdk version on each client
```

But none of the above solutions have worked for me..

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found it.

For my specific case, the resource directory is located in /var/lib/ambari-server/resources

I found that because in the error log (listed above), it shows that it's trying to look under the resources directory, so I used the find cmd.

```
find / -name *resources* .
```

I then simply just downloaded a copy of the exact jdk version that it was looking for (this is in the error log and mine was jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz) from the internet and placed it in the resource folder and everything worked.

Comment: Worked for me as well. 
`cp mysql-connector-java.jar /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/; ambari-server restart`